# Can I change controlling borders of selected two or more objects in Fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

I use fabridjs.

When I select one object, I can change controlling borders and controlling corner size as below.

```
var obj = new fabric.Image(oimg);
obj.set({ 
    cornerSize: 50,
    borderScaleFactor:7
});
```

[controlling borders of one object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcOxM.png)

When I select two or more objects, how can I change the controlling borders of the selected objects ?

Because my canvas is large, the controlling borders of the selected objects are too thin, so I want to enlarge the controlling borders.

[controlling borders of two objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWzJk.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use selected objects' group, reachable through `canvas.getActiveGroup()`. Then you should just need to use the same method you are using on objects, i.e :

```
var grp = canvas.getActiveGroup()
grp.set({
  cornerSize: 50,
  borderScaleFactor: 7
);
```

For complementary documentation, please see [fabricJs doc about Group](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I could achieve my aim. 
 `canvas.on('selection:created', function(){
    var grp = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    grp.set({
        cornerSize: 50,
        borderScaleFactor: 7
    });
});`

Comment: Since FabricJS 2.0, `getActiveGroup()` have been replaced with `canvas.getActiveObject().type === 'activeSelection'` : http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2